Did a real-world event inspire Mistral's "The Revolution of the Plants"?
Mistral's 1922 collection, Desolación ("Despair") is divided into seven parts: Vida, La Escuela, Infantiles, Dolor, Naturaleza, Prosa, and Prosa Escolar. In the Prosa Escolar ("School Prose") section she includes a number of stories or parables that could be used in schools to teach (Mistral herself was a teacher for many years).
The first of these is entitled Por qué las cañas son huecas, or Why the canes are hollow, a kind of Just-So story explaining why canes have hollow stems. The story explains that the canes whipped up the plant world to demand equality. The particular form of equality was not "for consistency in wood, or of goodness in the fruit, or the right to good water", but to be the same height, so that all plants from roses to oak trees would be equally tall.
With the help of the spirits of the earth ("los  genios  de  la  tierra") the plants achieved their aim, and overnight plants like wheat and clover grew to the heights of cathedrals, making impenetrable jungles. Although the canes rejoiced, the situation was not sustainable. The plants broke and withered, unable to sustain their size, so that "there was no bread or fruit for man, nor forage for the animals". The canes were the last to fall, and when they did:

It could then be seen that, from having been solid before the events
they had become hollow. They stretched out, stretching for leagues; But they had created a void within themselves...

After the fall, nature restored the plants to their proper states, with the exception of the canes, who were left to be "hollow, hollow..." as a mark of shame.
Was this revolution inspired by a real historical event? It is unusual in that the revolution was not for anything beneficial (like "better fruit" or "access to water"), but for something as pointless as being the same height. Is it a parody of some political movement of the time?

The first thought that came to mind was Communism, and the slogan “From each according to their ability, to each according to their need.” Not quite the same, but maybe close enough.

@PeterShor Was Mistral anti-communist? (a genuine question - I don't know). Neruda was a communist of course, but I don't know if they had similar politics.

Googling, it looks like she called herself a socialist. But that doesn't mean she approved of all varieties of Communism.
